# Why does my last customer entry override the previous entry instead of adding it to the customer object? JS

Tags: javascript

Why does my last customer entry override the previous entry instead of adding it to the customer object? JS
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class Bank {
    constructor() {
        this.customers = {};


    }
}

Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function (customer) {
    this.customers = customer;
    return this;

}
var bank = new Bank();
var newCustomer1 = bank.addCustomer('Curtis');
var newCustomer2 = bank.addCustomer('Alice');

console.log(bank.customers);
```

Comment: 1. `customers` is not an array but an object. 2. `this.customers = customer;` overwrites the entire value that was previously assigned anyway. You never attempt to *add*.

Comment: How does that not throw an exception? `bank.addCustomer` doesn't return anything, thus `newcustomer` is undefined. Then calling `newCustomer.addCustomer` won't work. Other than that, you should probably call `addCustomer` on the `bank` and not on the `newCustomer`

Answer (score 1):

First, customers is not an array, you have declared it as a Javascript Object.
Second, when you change it to an array, use the `push` method to add elements to the end of the array.

I've changed your code accordingly.

```
class Bank {
    constructor() {
        // Change 2
        this.customers = [];


    }
}

// Change 2
Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function (customer) {
    this.customers.push(customer);

}
var bank = new Bank();
bank.addCustomer('Curtis'); 
bank.addCustomer('Alice');
console.log(bank.customers);
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? `newCustomer` will be `undefined` as `addCustomer` doesn't return anything. Thus `newCustomer.addCustomer(...)` will throw an exception

Comment: `const newCustomer = bank.addCustomer;` and then `newCustomer('Curtis');` ... should that be okay, though @derpirscher ?

Comment: @jsN00b technically it would work, but it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @KaranBatavia ... please fix your broken code example ... `const bank = new Bank(); bank.addCustomer('Curtis'); bank.addCustomer('Alice'); console.log(bank.customers);` ... and since the implementation uses class syntax stay with it for the prototypal method instead of writing `Bank.prototype.addCustomer = ...`